# Cannot install Icinga Web 2 on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, icinga2, centos8, icingaweb2

I have installed Icinga2 on my server, which is running CentOS 8. However, I run into problems when I try and install Icinga Web 2.

When I try and run the command `yum -y install icingaweb2 icingacli`, CentOS cannot find the packages. The following output is given:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:04 ago on Sat 16 Nov 2019 23:22:22 NZDT.
No match for argument: icingaweb2
No match for argument: icingacli
Error: Unable to find a match
```

It also cannot find the packages `centos-release-scl` and `icingaweb2-selinux`.

I've added the Icinga repositories to CentOS manually, including EPEL relase, and they are showing in the yum.repos.d folder. But every time I try and install Icinga Web 2, whether with yum or dnf, I get the same error. I've tried `dnf makecache` and `yum makecache` and have updated the packages, but nothing seems to work.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

For install icinga via package management you should add this repo: https://packages.icinga.com/epel/